# Calculate time difference within one cell

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

I'm trying to calculate the time difference and get the result 04:00. This obviously doesn't work because MINUS expects 2 arguments and instead gets a range.

Generally, is there a way to output a range into a function kind of like the ES6 spread syntax in Javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(F22, " - "),,2) - 
 INDEX(SPLIT(F22, " - "),,1)
```

[image]

**This means we split the same cell twice.**
Using `INDEX` we use the second column of the first split minus the first column of the second split.
*(Of course you should format the result as duration.)*